# Fatal error during migration after fresh Phundament installation

Tags: yii, phundament

While installing Phundament first time i was asked to apply 12 migrations

```
Total 12 new migrations to be applied:
rights: m110402_195158_init
p3widgets: m110518_000000_init
p3media: m110719_000000_init
user: m110805_153437_installYiiUser
user: m110810_162301_userTimestampFix
rights: m111013_235001_p3items
p3widgets: m111028_000000_meta
p3widgets: m120309_021733_translation
p3pages: m120312_182502_init
p3pages: m121011_160518_fk_delete_cascade
p3media: m121011_170518_fk_delete_cascade
p3widgets: m121011_180518_fk_delete_cascade
```

I answered "yes" and earned this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strpos() in {myPathToP3}vendor/yiiext/migrate-command/EMigrateCommand.php on line 456
```

What does this mean for the state of my installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration did not run successfully. You should install/enable the [PHP mbstring extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) and then try to run the migration again.